# How to by pass Firebase Swift 3 Ambiguous reference to member 'observe(_:with)' error?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I know this question has been asked in the past but, I am unable to find a solution that works for swift 3. Could someone please point me in the right direction. Here is my code:

```
    ref.child(uid).child("flights").observe(.value, with:{  (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
        self.messages.append(snapshot)

        let row = [IndexPath(row: self.messages.count-1, section: 0) ]


        print(snapshot)

        self.flightTableView.insertRows(at: row, with: .automatic)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.flightTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I broke the code up into two statements and it started to work.

```
    let child:FIRDatabaseReference = ref.child(uid).child("flights")


    child.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 & Firebase 3.17.0**

This will do the trick, try this code

```
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("uid").child("flights")
        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("Success get the snapshot \(snapshot)")
            // do something with snapshot than
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.yourTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print("Failed get the snapshot \(error.localizedDescription)")
            // do something to handle error
        }
```